# Triggering Queries within a React-PDF Document

Tags: reactjs, redux, rtk-query, react-pdf

I am using React-PDF to create PDFs within my React application. My application is set up using RTK Query and works just as expected.

However, I am currently implementing my multipage PDF logic. Therefore I would like to use something like this:

```
function ComponentWithPDFEmbedded() {

  return (
    <div className="myClass">
      <PDFViewer>
        <PDFDoc />
      </PDFViewer>
    </div>
  );
}

function PDFDoc() {
  const {data} = useGetOverviewData();

  return (
    <Document>
      <CoverPage title={data.title}/>
      {data.pages.map((d) => <DetailPage key={d.id} id={d.id} />)}
      <AnotherDetailPage />
    </Document>
  );
}

function DetailPage({id}){
  const {data} = useGetDetailData({id});

  return (
    <Page>
      <View>
        <Text>{data.title}</Text>
      </View>
    </Page>
  );
}
```

However, this does not work as React-PDF seems to render in an iframe besides the React document tree. I am getting errors like this:

```
could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
```

Passing through the data as props is not really an option unfortunately, as the problem is quite a bit more complex with different queries and subviews. Any ideas how to access RTK Queries within the PDFDoc?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately passing your Redux "stuff" through as props is the only solution I'm aware of here, and it's exactly because the PDF UI is built/rendered into a completely separate DOMTree from where your main React app is rendered.

Comment: Hmm, thank you so much! I would be fine with passing some redux context as props so I could use the queries inside the PDF components and do not have to pass through all the data, if this would be possible.

Comment: I think you'd need to compute all the data "app-side" and pass the fetched/queried data down as props... basically all the Redux actions/queries/etc happen in your app and you pass down the overview and detail data as props.